# ngClass is not working inside ngFor for first condition in Angular 4

Tags: angular

I am trying to show the different icon inside for loop using [ngClass] with condition. Its perfectly working fine for second condition but its not working for first condition.

```
<i [ngClass]="{'fa fa-heart text-warning':z.isPinned == true,'fa fa-heart-o text-warning':z.isPinned == false}" (click)=addFavorite(z,i);  aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Environment: angular/cli - 1.5.0

Comment: Can you post the entire ngFor code? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the ternary operator:

```
[ngClass]="z.isPinned ? 'fa fa-heart text-warning' : 'fa fa-heart-o text-warning'"
```

Comment: Getting exception, Parser Error: Missing expected : at column 3 in [{z.isPinned ? 'fa fa-heart text-warning' :'fa fa-heart-o text-warning'}]

Comment: @PrabakarK Sorry, you need to remove the curly brackets, updated answer, try now :)

Comment: [ngClass]="z.isPinned ? 'fa fa-heart text-warning' :'fa fa-heart-o text-warning'" - this working without {}.

Comment: @PrabakarK Yeah, that was what I was indicating, and updated answer previously :)

Comment: Thanks for the updates. Sorry I didn't refresh the browser

Comment: Did it help? :)

Answer (score 0):

**Never use == operator, always ===**.

Also, have you checked if your `isPinned` actually has a truthy value ?

Finally, you can simplify with `'fa fa-heart text-warning': z.isPinned,'fa fa-heart-o text-warning': !z.isPinned`